# C++ Using Method on Vector (If is word)

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a couple methods defined, one checks if the next is a word, one checks if there is a next word.

I take inputs for the text files, add the files content to a vector, then use the for loop

I can make it work by simply doing a for loop through the vector:

```
 for (int x = 0; x != v2.size(); ++x) {
```

But I want to use my two methods

```
bool ReadWords::isNextWord()
```

and

```
string ReadWords::getNextWord()
{
 //take the input of the file until end of list is reached and return it

}
```

So how would I do something like

```
vector<string> bigTextFile;
vector<string> vct;

while(vct.isNextWord) {
      vct.getNextWord

      if(vct.getNextWord == bigTextFile[i] {
         counter++
     }
}
```

Let me know if you need any more of the code

Comment: C++ have many nice [algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). I'm sure you can *find* something useful.

Comment: You can't add functions to `std::vector`. It probably wouldn't hurt if you took a look at `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: Can you post your entire implementation ?

Comment: If you have to ask _"Let me know if you need any more of the code"_, the answer is probably yes, we do.

Comment: is `ReadWords` a class or a namespace? What are it's members?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
vector<string> bigTextFile;
vector<string> vct;

while(ReadWords::isNextWord(vct)) 
{
      string nextWord = ReadWords::getNextWord(vct);

      if(nextWord  == bigTextFile[i]) 
      {
         counter++;
      }
}
```

You could make your functions take in a vector as a parameter then do the work on the vector inside each function. I'm not 100% sure what your implementation is since its not the complete code.

Comment: I did try this once, but i get the error `no matching function for call to 'ReadWords::isNextWord(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)'|

Comment: Of course, because you haven't yet provided an overload of that function that takes that argument...

Comment: ^ yea you need to modify your code and the functions to accept a vector as a parameter/argument.

Comment: Hmm if im not allowed to edit my header file, i.e. leave the isNextWord as `bool isNextWord();` is it possible to only change the readWords cpp file to accept the vector as an argument?

Comment: Nope, the method/function definitions in the header MUST match the ones in the cpp

Comment: I see so I can't do this approach then, any tips on what I should do if i can only take a string for my getnextword and bool for isnextword? Is converting vector to a string a bad idea?

Comment: @Katianie Or maybe I shouldnt use a vector but a type of list/array that will accept my functions, because atm I do `while (myfile >> word) { vct.push_back(word);}`

What would be a better string store than a vector?

Comment: Binary Search Tree, Dictionary, Hash Table, or even a custom made data structure. vector is great though since its an array/queue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you trying to write an object, but here is how I would have approached the problem:

Step 1. Create a predicate for the words

```
bool is_needed_word(const std::string& word, const std::vector<std::string>& needed_words)
{
    if (std::find(needed_words.begin(), 
                  needed_words.end(), 
                  word) != needed_words.end())
        return true;
}

//some where in your function
std::vector<std::string> needed_words{"apple", "moon", "etc"};
auto predicate = [&needed_words](const auto& word)
                 {return is_needed_word(word, needed_words);}
```

Step 2. Copy/count/whatever you want to do with the words in the stream

```
//copying
std::vector<std::string> extracted_words;
std::ifstream input_file{"input.txt"};
//check if opened correctly
std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(input_file), {},
             std::back_inserter(extracted_words));

//counting
std::size_t occurrence_counter = std::count_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(input_file),{},predicate)
```

Comment: A more advanced answer using find and predicate algorithms. Points for not re-inventing the wheel.